# Azure Databricks Delta Table vs Azure Synapse Lake Database Table

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-lake

I am struggling to understand something here and im sure the answer is simple....when I run this command in a Databrick note book:

```
(df.write
 .format("delta")
 .option("path", "/file/path/location")
 .saveAsTable("MyTable"))
```

It creates a delta table. Okay Great!
but if I run the same command in azure synapse spark notebook....it creates a table...
Does Synapse now support delta tables? According to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386446/using-delta-tables-in-azure-synapse-dedicated-serverless-sql-pools#:%7E:text=Delta%20is%20not%20supported%20in%20Synapse.%20You,can%20vote%20for%20this%20item%20here%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Ffeedback.azure.com%2Fforums%2F307516-azure-synapse-analytics%2Fsuggestions%2F41120794-delta-lake-support-to-sql-on-demand) it does not.

So my question is...whats the difference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Synapse Analytics has a number of engines such as Spark and SQL. Synapse Spark pools [support Delta Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-delta-lake-overview?pivots=programming-language-python). Synapse Serverless SQL pools recently [supports reading from Delta Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-delta-lake-format). Synapse Dedicated SQL Pools do not support Delta Lake at this moment.

That other StackOverflow answer is out of date. It was only discussing Synapse Serverless SQL Pools. I added a comment asking him to update it.

Comment: Is there a way to set a data retention policy for the logs and files of delta tables in serverless sql pools?

Comment: @dragon_fury_ for delta table, you can use the 'vacuum' command: https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#remove-files-no-longer-referenced-by-a-delta-table